# Change hyphenation patterns only for a chapter

Tags: lyx, languages, hyphenation, babel

I am currently writing a book in Italian using LyX and I use

```
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
```

in the preamble. However, I need to write a chapter of this book in a different language.
How can I change the hyphenation only for this chapter to English?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insert an ERT using `\selectlanguage{english}` and revert back using the inverse. From the [`babel`](http://ctan.org/pkg/babel) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/babel/babel.pdf) (section **1 The user interface**, p 4):

> When a user wants to switch from one language to another he can do so using
>   the macro `\selectlanguage`. This macro takes the language, deﬁned previously
>   by a language deﬁnition ﬁle, as its argument. It calls several macros that should
>   be deﬁned in the language deﬁnition ﬁles to activate the special deﬁnitions for the
>   language chosen.

Comment: What is an ERT?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: In LyX this is referred to as "Evil Red Text" that inserted in the Wysiwyg LyX editor to include any LaTeX code.

Comment: Nowadays with LyX 2.0.x, ERT is called "TeX code" and the button on the toolbar looks like the "TEX" logo of this site. (A little inconsistent that hovering over such a "TeX code" field displays "ERT".)

Answer (score 4):

`babel` supports changing the hyphenrules

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chiao}
foo

\begin{hyphenrules}{english}
\chapter{Hello}
bar
\end{hyphenrules}

\chapter{Italiano}
baz
\end{document}
```

you can insert the two command lines into LyX with `Ctrl-L` also called ERT (Evil Red Text)

Comment: If the language es `english`, `hyphenrules` is ok, but in general the right environment is `otherlanguage*`.